# Numerical evaluation of Duhamel's integration

Tags: matlab, integration, time-integration, convolution

I am trying to numerically evaluate the following Duhamel's integration:

$$
x = \frac{-1}{\omega_d} \int_0^t \ddot{x}_g (\tau) e^{-\zeta \omega_n(t - \tau)} \sin{\left( \omega_d (t - \tau) \right)} d\tau
$$
where $\omega_d$, $\zeta$ and $\omega_n$ are constants.

From our data, $\ddot{x}_g(t_i)$ are given at each discrete time increment $t_i$, but I am struggle to compute $x(t_i)$, or the Duhamel's integral, correctly?

In my MATLAB script, I have tried to store $e^{-\zeta \omega_n(t_i)} \sin{\left( \omega_d (t_i) \right)} $ to an array `H`, and then the numerical value of $\ddot{x}(t_i)$ for $i = 1, \cdots N$ is stored inside another array `xdd` (same dimension as `H`). I then tried to use the convolution function inside MATLAB, i.e.:

```
X = conv(xdd, H)
```

However, it does not look like my attempts are working out. My questions, along with what I have tried, are:

1. From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html), the resulting length for `X` is `length(xdd) + length(H) - 1`, but shouldn't the dimension of `X` be the same with `xdd` (used to store $\ddot{x}$)? I would expect that at each value of $\ddot{x}$, there would be a corresponding value of $x$. Therefore, `X` and `xdd` should have the same dimension. But that doesn't seem to be the case here...
2. I have also tried the `'same'` for the Shape options from the MATLAB documentation above, but that also doesn't seem to give me the right answers. The resulting `X` that I got is at a much higher frequency that what we would expect analytically.
3. Is this the correct strategy to arrive at the numerical solution for $x$?

Comment: Its generally discouraged to post the same question on multiple sites: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4324237/418145

Comment: It looks like the problem here is some confusion about MATLAB functions, and those can be sorted out by trying first a very simple integral, $\int^t d\tau$, and building up from there in small incremental steps. Also, this problem apparently can be approached as an ODE, if you take the time derivative of your equation, and that may be a more convenient way to deal with it.